# Code to get *.aspx in a website

Tags: asp.net, directory-traversal

Is there a method to get all of the .aspx files in my website? Maybe iterate through the site's file structure and add to an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"/"), "*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 1):

using Directory.GetFiles("*.aspx"), you can get all the files in the directory. And you can make it recursive to grab any sub directories and their files.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you can define an .aspx page without having an actual file be there in the web.config.